SMD transistors are big and I can't find a PNP common collector array on a single chip
I am continuing work on my water management system including the tank level meter discussed here Water level meter with electrodes: earthing and galvanic corrosion and my solution with the PNP transistors. I have built on breadboard, and of course that's impossible to use in production, I have made my 3D soldered contraptions with 9 TO92 transistors glued on a resistor array as a back bone with the 74HC148 soldered on top, and all of that was a lot of work but ended up failing. So now I need to take the plunge into getting PCBs made, and SMD form factor is of course the way to go. Bye bye through the hole technology of the 1980s.
However I find that relatively speaking, transistor packages in SMD footprint are huge! They are in packs comparable in size to 6 pin ICs but have only 3 pins connected or present. So if I need 9 of them they take huge real estate, when in the through-hole mount technology they were -- relatively speaking -- much smaller. Therefore my interest in higher integration with transistor arrays. I need PNP and common emitter is useless for me. If anything common, so be it the collector. But I see others ask for it on Google and can't find much in actually available production.
What trick I am missing? For example, in the question for the common collector PNP, they are responding with suggestions of Darlington pairs and even buffers, but I find that confusing because what I need is a common ground electrode and anodes connected to the base of PNP transistors so they would pull the emitter to ground when the PNP conducts through 10 kOhm resistors one for each PNP emitter. I cannot find a transistor array for that and would have to use a big area on the PCB for these big transistor packages.
What am I thinking wrong here?

Package size can be less than 1x1 mm. But probably you will want to be able to solder it without a reflow oven, and heat dissipation is poor for smaller packages. How much current do you need to be able to handle?

And what are your control voltages? (i.e. could you use a MOSFET instead?)

Quad PNP in 6x10 mm package

SMD transistors are often relatively much larger than other components, because people who buy individual transistors are often using them for power switching (e.g. motor control) and they need to be that large to avoid overheating.  Or phototransistors, which need more area to collect more light.  Engineers who care about miniaturization of low power transistors are usually buying (at least) large scale integrated logic (which is not very integrated by today's standards -- it was when the name was coined).

@ThePhoton MMPQ2907A is exactly what I need! Funny how the collector pins are duplicated, but it's perfect layout for just soldering them on a common ground bar, very easy!

@GuntherSchadow, the doubled collector pins is probably to improve thermal performance.

A TO-92 package is 4mm wide across the largest diameter. SOT-23 is 2.9mm across, SOT-323/SC-70 is 2.0mm, and a SOT-523 is just 1.6mm, but there are fewer options and it may be difficult to hand solder that one. At that scale, the leads contribute quite a bit to the footprint area, so a no-lead package might be a logical next step, with the tradeoff of being even more difficult to solder.
Remember that at any significant current, there will be a good deal of heat to dissipate - more than a MOSFET - so small package sizes can be self defeating in that respect.

You are of course right in absolute size, but I spoke of relative size. But I understand why that would be, heat dissipation. Makes sense!

If you're short on space, there are dual transistors in SOT-363, the two transistors are independent so it's only about saving space. At 2x2mm it's still hand solderable. SOT-563 is smaller at 1.6x1.2mm. If you have it assembled you can go smaller with leadless packages both in duals and singles.
